# can a web parser differentiate between static and dynamic text?

Tags: browser, server-side

Can a web parser differentiate between static and dynamic text on a webpage?
For example there is a string on a webpage

> Hello "Fantastic Four"

In this "Hello" is a static data and "Fantastic Four" is a dynamic data (say being populated form a database value)

Is it possible for web parser to detect which is a static and dynamic content?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "static and dynamic content"? Content generated in JavaScript vs. HTML? Also, what do you mean by a "web parser"? Do you mean a crawler?

Comment: If you are talking about static Html vs server-generated Html, then you cannot know. If you are talking about some javascript executing at the client side, then it depends, but sounds difficult. Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I'm talking about server generated HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it's not possible. The client can't know anything about the executing code in the server, so there is no way that know if the text has been generated by PHP, ASP or any other language... or even is static.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the URL and HTTP headers to make an educated guess if the file was served statically (directly from the filesystem) or generated. Most "web page parsers" don't get this information, however, and almost all generated pages have static bits in them. (Sometimes those are included directly in the source code, or they could be from a template or SSI file.) Distinguishing those static bits from the rest is impossible.